# How to replace a word if it is in a file name?

Tags: cmd

I have multiple files

```
P_H_Home.png
P_Log.png
D_H_Car.png
```

I need to replace `_H_` with `_G_`
And I want get

```
P_G_Home.png
P_Log.png
D_G_Car.png
```

How can i do this?

I am not very familiar with CMD/BAT And now I just want to rename all files It should look something like this but work

```
for %I in (*) do  ren "%I" "%I"str:_H_=_G_
```

Comment: Explain "Preferably one line", clarify whether you want to replace the upper case `H` character for an upper case `G` character, or whethet this is a case insensitive change. And please show us what you've tried based upon reference answers, because you know what you've posted is not a genuine attempt at the task.

Comment: @Compo I want to replace an uppercase character that has hyphens namely "_H_" with "_G_". Because the symbol "_H_" can also be used as a capital letter in the name. Example "P_H_Home" I need get "P_G_Home" no "P_G_Gome"

Comment: So why not explain that in your question? You want to replace the upper case character `H` in the sequence `_H_` with `G`. As you wrote it, it appeared you wanted to replace all `H` characters with `G` characters. There is an [edit] button you can use to fix your question, explain why a single line command is preferred, (or why a batch file cannot be used), and show your coding attempts. BTW, they are underscores, (_), not hyphens, (-),

Comment: @Compo I have corrected my question. I did not immediately notice, but for some reason the hyphens were not shown in the body of the question. I hope it's more clear now

Comment: Yes, that is because `_` is a site markup character whereby \_string\_ is italicized, i.e. _string_. Thanks for the correction, what about the other information I asked for?